# Express js error while trying to create a post request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post

I was trying to create a post request in order to crate an "Offer".
Unfortunately everytime I try to send data it keeps returning an error and I didn't know why it doesn't work ! can someone help me please ?

this is my express API

```
router.post('/create-offer', (req, res) => {

Offer = new Offer({
    Title: req.body.Title,
    Position: req.body.Position,
    Location: req.body.Location,
    Duration: req.body.Duration,
    WorkingHours: req.body.WorkingHours
   // OfferDescription: req.body.OfferDescription,
   // Tags: req.body.Tags,
})

Offer
.save()
.then(data => {
  res.json(data);
})
.catch(err => {
  res.status(500).send({
    message:
      err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Offer."
  });
});
return res.send('Received a POST HTTP method');
```

})

and this is my mongodb model:

[image]

I always keep getting error 500
[image]

Comment: various issues, but `Offer = new Offer` wont help things

Comment: So can you help me ?!

Comment: change the Offer variable to something else it will override your model (or if is const, cause errors), then delete `return res.send('Received a POST HTTP method');` line as it will cause headers already sent error, which your currently be seeing from servers console

Comment: It's working thank you so much !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```js
router.post('/offer', (req, res) => { // create-offer -> offer
const offer = new Offer({ // offer -> Offer
    Title: req.body.Title,
    Position: req.body.Position,
    Location: req.body.Location,
    Duration: req.body.Duration,
    WorkingHours: req.body.WorkingHours
})

return offer
  .save()
  .then(data => {
    return res.json(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).json({
      message:
        err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Offer."
    });
  });
});

// remove res.send('...'), you can only give one response, using `res.send` and `res.json` will send two responses.
```